# Protractor How to call already defined customerlocator.js in an external file in my protractor spec.js file

Tags: protractor

As per the https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator

I created buttontextcusloc.js and placed inside of customlocators folder. File content is as per the below.

```
var buttontxtcustomlocator = function() {


by.addLocator('buttonTextSimple',
        function(buttonText, opt_parentElement, opt_rootSelector) {
      // This function will be serialized as a string and will execute in the
      // browser. The first argument is the text for the button. The second
      // argument is the parent element, if any.
      var using = opt_parentElement || document,
      buttons = using.querySelectorAll('button');
      // Return an array of buttons with the text.
      return Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function(button) {
       return button.textContent === buttonText;
```

});
}

module.exports = new buttontxtcustomlocator();

This is my customloctestcase.spec.js which inside com/sam/scripts

```
 describe('Custom Locator Script', function() {

  it("check customr locator ",function()
  {
      browser.driver.get("http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/registeration/#/login");
    // Use the custom locator.
      element(by.buttonTextSimple('Go!')).click();
});

  });
```

In my config.js I have added like below

```
var cl = require('customlocators/buttontextcusloc.js');
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
```

However after I ran it , I get below error .

[image]

Project structure as per the below . Command I used to run is protractor defaultconfig.js
[image]

Comment: How do you run protractor tests? Which command and in which directory are you using ?

Comment: Could you show your directory structure?

Comment: Package structure  is added in the question itself. I modified , Kindly see and I;m running this via cmd by navigating EclipsePro which is my project location .

Comment: Did you tried to specify a full path - "./customlocators/buttontextcusloc.js"?

Comment: Yes , by the way I'm not sure the accuracy of my spec.js and config.js .If anyone has a working sample , please share them .Thank you .

Comment: Still don't know why it cannot locate the module but I have also noticed that you did not add your locator to the global Protractor object. You can do it in onPrepare function